# 16.04 Shortcuts launching programs (Terminal, Nautilus) not working anymore

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Standard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal doesn't work anymore.
Custom shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open Nautilus doesn't work anymore.

Both worked fine until a reboot. The only thing I did in between is messing with my display resolution:

- created new cvt line
- added resolution via `xrandr`
- applied resolution

I did this before, restarted in between. No problem. The only new thing I did this time was:

- tried to make change persistent by creating a .xprofile file as suggested here: [How do I save my new resolution setting with xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754231/how-do-i-save-my-new-resolution-setting-with-xrandr)

Other shortcuts, like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd> are still working. I also tried to assign a new shortcut to those to "launch" operations but they didn't work as well.

Probably not a keyboard hardware related issue, as it's neither working on the notebook's internal keyboard nor an external one.

Comment: Which DE? May be an issue with the DE

Comment: Unity. One more thing I noticed are dual menu bars in several programs (in the windows title bar (as set in the global Appearance settings) as well as an extra one in the program window. Some programs like the terminal won't let me even turn the extra one off. Also the GUI of some programs, QGIS for instance looks different now. More blocky.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rm -rf ~/.config`

seems like a temporary (hardcore) solution to the problem. It deletes all desktop settings.

This works, but the problem reappeared after a failed attempt to change the resolution again as mentioned above. As long as I don't choose a display resolution which fails to be set, the problem doesn't reappear.

Comment: Removing the monitors.xml from the .config dir only works as well, while preserving a lot of other configurations