# Set default screen of xrandr in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, display-resolution

I recently ran a windows game with wine on `Xubuntu`. It resized my screen size and using

```
xrandr -s 0
```

it fixes. But I need to do this each time after boot. I used [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/754233/268874) and I wrote above command in `~/.xprofile`, but it not works.

I want to set my default screen size after boot being `0`. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You need to add a little break, see "important note" in the dupe: http://askubuntu.com/a/637921/72216