# What is the difference between ~/.config/autostart and ~/.config/autostart-scripts?

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, directory, autostart

I have Kubuntu 17.10, trying to copy a .desktop file into the autostart directory then I figured out that I don't have it, just the directory `~/.config/autostart-scripts`

I do not know if they have the same purspose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have it, create it

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart/
```

As for the `~/.config/autostart-scripts` file, it is documented in [ArchWiki article on KDE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE):

```
~/.config/autostart-scripts
    for executing scripts at login
```

So this can be used to run shell commands, export environment variables, etc. Also, according to post by [claydoh](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=128113#p341248) on kde forum:

> ...using the tool to add scripts seems to place them in ~/.config/autostart-scripts, and not as .desktop files.

Comment: On my 17.04, using the tool put them as Desktop files in ~/.config/autostart when added with "Startup Applications"

Answer (score 10):

The `autostart` directory is a part of the freedesktop.org/XDG [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html). Per that spec, a compliant desktop environment will search `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart` for any [`.desktop`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) files and execute them on startup. KDE Plasma 5 (the DE used in Kubuntu), specifically, complies with this spec.

The `autostart-scripts` directory doesn't appear to be a part of any standard. It's a [hardcoded](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/b368bd1b04b4013b18e400666d0bc79b6c4b30f0/kcms/autostart/autostart.cpp#L151) directory that Plasma searches for executable scripts (that is, actual executable files, not readable `.desktop` files) and likewise executes them on startup.

As was said in [Sergiy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971110/453741), you can create the `autostart` directory if you so choose, but it's entirely optional.

---

For example, on my system, I use a `.desktop` file, `~/.config/autostart/xrdb.desktop`, to load my X resource settings (`urxvt` settings/colorschemes, mostly):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=X resources loader
Exec=xrdb -merge .Xresources
Comment=Load X resource files on startup of DE
```

It follows that the command `xrdb -merge .Xresources` is executed upon startup of KDE Plasma 5, and so my settings are loaded.

Also, this `.desktop` file shows up in the Plasma settings like so, which would be how I could graphically configure other `.desktop` entries to be auto-started:

[image: Settings dialog example]