# How to get the 2560x1440 resolution option permanently under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I just bought an Acer K272HUL 27" monitor capable of 1440 resolution to use with a 4k laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 and a Nvidia 960M GPU. I followed the directions here(I needed to use cvt - r  since this model blanks)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Everything seems to work great. I get 2650x1440 on the Acer. My problem is how to make this permanent? The instructions say to create an entry in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf but I don't think I have that file under Ubuntu 18.04. How do I make this resolution option permanent?

These are the files/directories under /etc/X11/
`
app-defaults             rgb.txt  Xreset.d    Xsession.options
cursors                  xinit    Xresources  xsm
default-display-manager  xkb      Xsession    XvMCConfig
fonts                    Xreset   Xsession.d  Xwrapper.config

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268678/best-place-to-automatically-add-mode-in-xrandr and https://askubuntu.com/q/754231/57576

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I think this may have worked.

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

added to the end of the file and saved

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440R"  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 2560x1440R
```

Anyone see any issues this might cause?

This is where I found this solution.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: why do you have R after 2560x1440 ?