# Adding a Monitor (AL1716) which isn't correctly supported in 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, display, display-resolution, intel-nuc

I'm ready to deploy my NUC8i3 running Ubuntu 18.04LST into it's final location. Although I normally plan to connected to it remotely I still want to have a monitor where it will be located. I have an old Acer AL1716 but I'm having problems getting Ubuntu to correctly use the monitor. Everything comes up until I get to the Login screen at which point nothing works.

I think that the problem is the settings built into Ubuntu. Although it shows a 75 and 60 Hz settings, which the AL1716 supports, they are not ones that the AL1716 will use. It needs the settings that are just slightly different namely 60Hz should be 63.67Hz. Not sure about the 75Hz one since I've not tried it yet.

I've done through several steps and been able to get Ubuntu to get the monitor to work but only after losing in. I preformed the following.

```
    $ cvt 1280 1024 60

1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1280x1024_60.00"

$ sudo xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 60
```

At this point the AL1716 will display correctly. The problem is that I can't see this as a selection I can use using the normal display setup nor can I use this to see the login screen.

What I really want to do is add settings to the standard monitor tables, I assume that Ubuntu has such tables for each monitor it supports, so the AL1716 has the correct settings no matter which user I login with.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I run the following to remove what I added: "$ sudo xrandr --delmode DP-1 "1280x1024_60.00"" but it seems it wasn't added. It seems that when I issue the "sudo xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 60" or "sudo xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 75" the display does indeed come on using the built in values. However, if you use the display application to set the values they don't work even though they should be using the same values. When you use the render command both look like the same values have been set. I have no idea why this is.

Comment: Still have no idea how to get the login page to display even though the 1280x1024 settings survive a reboot. It seems to always come up in 1980x1024.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/754233/260379) may work saving the settings on the profile so it will be load after login. And/or you can run a script to set the correct display settings if the monitor is detected using xrandr + grep.