# How can I scale multiple screens?

Tags: display, display-resolution, scaling

I am currently working on a Windows desktop and use Ubuntu at home. At work, I have 4 screens in total and 3 of them are different sizes.

Resolutions:

- screen one: 3000x2000
- screen two: 2560x1440
- screens three and four: 1920x1080

Why can't I scale one screen and not the others? If I don't scale I can't read anything on screen one, but if I scale everything is too big on screen three and four. I have tried different display managers, desktop environments and some differen distros.

Currently I am stuck in Windows because of this.

Comment: Have a look at this maybe it can help you : https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens

Comment: Also if you choose xrandr see this for some additional help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/754231/how-do-i-save-my-new-resolution-setting-with-xrandr

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the aspect ratio is 16:9 by going to **System Settings → Devices → Display Resolution**.

Note that the ratio 16:9 means full screen actually!

Comment: Hello.I am sorry but what does aspect ration have to do with this?

Comment: hey. as i understand him i answered if you have a solution till us we here to help each other and thanks for sharing .

Comment: Aspect ration does not solve the problem with different dpi on each monitor

Comment: What he needs is a way to set a different dpi scaling on each monitor