# How to maximize the screen of Ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, fullscreen, maximized

I have installed **Ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox**. Now the screen I am viewing is not the maximized one. I want to maximize it as the primary operating systems' screen resolution by **adding any guest additions** or if any or way is also available please recommend me with full detail...

Comment: Are you running VirtualBox in full screen mode but Ubuntu is not using the entire screen area?

Comment: Yes Matigo. You stated right!

Comment: I would recommend [looking at this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130337/1091774) which will show you how to add new modes with `xrandr` and have the VM auto-load the profile when starting 

Answer (score 0):

This should just work after installing Guest Additions and rebooting:

1. Download guest additions on your host system. Make sure you choose the same version as the VB software running on the host.
2. Start your VM
3. Using the devices menu from within the VM insert the Guest Additions CD image in the virtual optical drive
4. A window should pop up asking if you want to run VBox_GAs. Click Run. This will install Guest Additions.
5. Reboot the VM and you should be able to change the screen resolution and use the view menu to choose the kind of view you want.

Good luck